# Safari browser on windows desktop not being responsive with CSS @media

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, safari

Safari browser on windows desktop not being responsive with CSS, 
this is my example that wont work on safari but works completely fine on every other browser:

```
<style>
#wrape{
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: green
}
@media screen and (max-width:750px){
   #wrape {
     display: none
   }
}
</style>

<div id="wrape"></div>
```

This is very confusing and I kept researching to find the correct solution to solve this problem and this is what I have found so far.

To place this meta tag inside head tags:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
```

To change the CSS code to:

**Possible solution 1**

```
@media only screen and (max-width:750px) {
  #wrape {
     display: none
  }
}
```

**Possible solution 2**

```
@media (max-width:750px) {
  #wrape {
     display: none
  }
}
```

**Possible solution 3**

```
@media screen and (min-device-width:750px) and (max-width:750px){
  #wrape {
     display: none
  }
}
```

I also tried overwriting any CSS style with `#wrape { display:none !important }`

I cant seem to find any solutions that works, I would appropriate any help.

Comment: Its looks fine in my desktop when viewing with browserstack (win8/safari)

Answer (score 0):

Try this ( without the min-device-width )

```
@media screen and (max-width:750px){ 
  #wrape {
     display: none
  }
}
```